# SH file under Windows Ubuntu - Change directory not working

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I created a `test.sh` file and tried to run `sudo ./test.sh`

In that SH file, CD does not work, not able to find path.  CD to a mounted drive like `CD /mnt/e/myfolder/myfolder1`

I am running Ubuntu inside Windows.

Comment: do you had add permissions to you bash file?

Comment: Do `cat -A` on the script file, see if it's saved with Windows line ending.  Common problem, rule this out first

Comment: Do you mean `CD` or rather `cd`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the full error message, and the whole script (or at least the line that doesn't work).

Comment: You'll probably want to avoid using `sudo` until you can debug the script.